# Declare a empty variable

Tags: xslt

I wrote :-

```
<xsl:variable name="cAddress" select=""></xsl:variable>
```

I don't want to assign any value here, I want to assign later. Is this possible?

Comment: Could it be that you are looking for passing a parameter to a template?

Comment: Yes that what I m doing

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. In XSLT, variables are immutable. You cannot assign - or reassign - a value to an existing variable. Technically, you can declare an empty variable as:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar"/>
```

but you won't be able to do anything with it later.

---

If you want to pass a **parameter** to a stylesheet or to a template at runtime, use:

```
<xsl:param name="cAddress"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:param name="cAddress" select="'default value'"/>
```